# Wildfly 8.0.0.Final - timer service cluster support

Tags: java, jboss, scheduled-tasks, wildfly

Does Wildfly 8.0.0.Final support clustering for timer service? I would like to run wildfly on multiple instances with shared database. Only one instance should be able to run job annotated with `javax.ejb.Schedule` at the same time. According to [this](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/EJB3+Clustered+Database+Timers) documentation it works when you set the same parition name and transaction isolation level to `READ_COMMITED`. I have simmilar setup, but all instances start the same job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since JBoss 7, JBoss 7.x and Wildfly 8.x don't have support for cluster timers.
In Wildfly 9 this feature is added:

- [EJB timers in cluster and failover support](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-283)
- [EJB3 Clustered Database Timers - WildFly 9](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/EJB3+Clustered+Database+Timers)

Alternatively you can use [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-11) or implement a Singleton Service.

[A SingletonService deployed in a JAR started by SingletonStartup and accessed by an EJB](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/master/cluster-ha-singleton)

Comment: @Konrad you can use CDI for injection, look this link http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/05/how-to-quartz-scheduler-with-clustering-in-jee-application-with-mysql.html

Comment: the SingletonService solution works very well under WildFly 8.1.